# Most idiomatic way to print a time difference in Java?

Tags: java, datetime, idioms, code-formatting

I'm familiar with printing time difference in milliseconds:

```
 long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
 //do something that takes some time...
 long completedIn = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
```

But, is there a nice way print a complete time in a specified format (eg: HH:MM:SS) either using Apache Commons or even the dreaded platform API's Date/Time objects? In other words, what is the shortest, simplest, no nonsense way to write a time format derived from milliseconds in Java?

Comment: Should be `System.currentTimeMillis() - time;`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Apache Commons has the [DurationFormatUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DurationFormatUtils.html) class for applying a specified format to a time duration.  So, something like:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
//do something that takes some time...
long completedIn = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;

DurationFormatUtils.formatDuration(completedIn, "HH:mm:ss:SS");
```

Comment: You could even inline that to:
DurationFormatUtils.formatDuration(System.currentTimeMillis() - time, "HH:mm:ss:SS");

Comment: Or use the almost identical, built-in DurationFormatUtils.formatDurationHMS(end-start);

Comment: @JRL: `DurationFormatUtils.formatDurationHMS(end-start);` will satisfy the example given in the question, but I added the milliseconds in my solution.

Comment: yep! Although `formatDurationHMS` doesn't quite fit the requirements as it's `H:m:s` and not `HH:mm:ss`, but I just wanted to point it out as a possibility.

Comment: This work can now be done without 3rd-party libraries: See `Duration` & `Period` classes in the *java.time* packages to represent a span-of-time unattached to the timeline.

Answer (score 5):

A library designed for the purpose is the better approach, but [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with the right `TimeZone` may suffice for periods less than a day. Longer periods require treating the day specially.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Elapsed {

    private static final long MS_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    private final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH : mm : ss : S");

    public Elapsed() {
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    }

    private String format(long elapsed) {
        long day = elapsed / MS_DAY;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(day);
        sb.append(" : ");
        sb.append(df.format(new Date(elapsed)));
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Elapsed e = new Elapsed();
        for (long t = 0; t < 3 * MS_DAY; t += MS_DAY / 2) {
            System.out.println(e.format(t));
        }
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
0 : 00 : 00 : 00 : 0
0 : 12 : 00 : 00 : 0
1 : 00 : 00 : 00 : 0
1 : 12 : 00 : 00 : 0
2 : 00 : 00 : 00 : 0
2 : 12 : 00 : 00 : 0
```

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
Duration.ofMillis( … )
        .toString()
```

…or…

```
Duration.between(      // `Duration` represents a span of time unattached to the timeline, in a scale of days-hours-minutes-seconds-nanos.
    instantEarlier ,   // Capture the current moment to start.
    Instant.now()      // Capture the current moment now, in UTC.
)                      // Returns a `Duration` object.
.toString()            // Generate a string in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> PT1M23.407S

## ISO 8601

> what is the shortest, simplest, no nonsense way to write a time format derived from milliseconds

The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines textual formats for date-time values. These formats are indeed short, simple, and no-nonsense. They are largely human-readable across various cultures, practical, and unambiguous.

For spans of time unattached to the timeline, the [standard format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) is `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`. The `P` marks the beginning, and the `T` separates the years-month-days from the hours-minutes-seconds. So an hour and a half is `PT1H30M`.

## `java.time.Duration`

The java.time classes include a pair of classes to represent spans of time. The [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class is for hours-minutes-seconds, and `Period`.

## `Instant`

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant earlier = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
… 
Instant later = Instant.now() ;

Duration d = Duration.between( earlier , later ) ;
String output = d.toString() ;
```

> PT3.52S

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to see a millisecond difference, I don't think there's a shorter, simpler way.

If you need a more powerful (but certainly not simpler) way to collect performance statistics, there is [Perf4J](http://perf4j.codehaus.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Not to my knowledge.  But [printf()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) can do this easily if you calculate the values for H, M and S, and use a %02 pattern for each.

Answer (score 0):

```
long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
int hours = (int)(diff / 3600000); diff -= hours * 3600000;
int mins = (int)(diff / 60000); diff -= mins * 60000;
int secs = (int)(diff / 1000); diff -= secs * 1000;
System.out.println(String.format("%d:%d:%d.%d", hours, mins, secs, diff));
```