# Java pretty print for duration

Tags: java, timespan, pretty-print

Is there Java class or some sample code that can convert a java Date or Timestamp into something like:

```
"3 hours"
" 20 seconds"
 "25 minutes"
```

I need those strings in my web application to show how much it took to generate a file (in a pretty print way of course :) )

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/):

```
PeriodFormat.getDefault( ).print( Hours.THREE );
PeriodFormat.getDefault( ).print( Seconds.seconds( 25 ) );
PeriodFormat.getDefault( ).print( Minutes.minutes( 20 ) );
```

P.S. Also it's very easy to get the number of hours/seconds/minutes between 2 time points.

Answer (score 3):

Using JodaTime is the best overall approach, but here's one way to do it without using any domain-specific libraries, using the [`ChoiceFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/ChoiceFormat.html) indirectly in the context of a [`MessageFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html):

```
static String choiceFor(int index, String noun) {
    return "{index,choice,0#|1#1 noun |1<{index,number,integer} nouns }"
        .replace("index", String.valueOf(index))
        .replace("noun", noun);
}
static String prettyPrint(int h, int m, int s) {
    String fmt = 
        choiceFor(0, "hour") +
        choiceFor(1, "minute") +
        choiceFor(2, "second");
    return java.text.MessageFormat.format(fmt, h, m, s).trim();
}
```

Now you can have ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/r3uN2)):

```
    System.out.println(prettyPrint(1,2,3));
    // 1 hour 2 minutes 3 seconds

    System.out.println(prettyPrint(0,0,7));
    // 7 seconds

    System.out.println(prettyPrint(1,0,1));
    // 1 hour 1 second

    System.out.println(prettyPrint(0,2,0));
    // 2 minutes
```

You can of course extend this to include days/months/years/etc.

Answer (score 2):

you can get the hours, minutes and seconds from java `Calendar` class and then concat them with what ever you like (hours , mins ...)

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeinMillis(<the time in milli second format (a long number)>);

int hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int mins = c.get(Calendar.MIN);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds very much like [TimeAgo](http://timeago.yarp.com/). You may be able to leverage the code in there to format durations like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try using SimpleDateFormat:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: With the right `TimeZone`, it's feasible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705674