# How to convert minutes to Hours and Minutes (hh:mm) in Java?

Tags: java

I need to convert minutes to *hours* and *minutes* in Java. For example 260 minutes should be `4:20`.

Can anyone help me how to do such conversion?

Comment: 24 hour time or 12 hour time with am and pm?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704473

Comment: Convert to a `Duration`, for example `Duration dur = Duration.ofMinutes(260);`. Format through `String.format(Locale.forLanguageTag("en-IN"), "%d:%02d", dur.toHours(), dur.toMinutesPart())`. Result: `4:20`.

Answer (score 226, accepted):

If your time is in a variable called `t` :

```
int hours   = t / 60;   // since both are ints, you get an int
int minutes = t % 60;
System.out.printf("%d:%02d", hours, minutes);
```

It couldn't get easier.

---

### Addendum from 2021

Please notice that this answer is about the *literal meaning* of the question: how to convert an amount of minute to hours + minutes. It has nothing to do with time, time zones, AM/PM etc.

If you need better control about this kind of stuff, i.e. you're dealing with moments in time and not just an amount of minutes and hours, see [Basil Bourque's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41800301/133203) below.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this with Java 8 `Duration`?

Comment: If `t` can be `<0` (negative) then the second line should be `int minutes = Math.abs(t) % 60;`.

Comment: and also if you want am or pm with time  add this condition 
 String amOrPm;
     if (timeInminutes>=720)
      amOrPm="PM";
      else
       amOrPm="AM";
     String convertedTime=hours +":" +minutes+amOrPm;

Comment: What to do with non-AM/PM locales? This is only partial, non localized solution.

Answer (score 43):

## tl;dr

```
Duration.ofMinutes( 260L )
        .toString()
```

> PT4H20M

… or …

```
LocalTime.MIN.plus( 
    Duration.ofMinutes( 260L ) 
).toString()
```

> 04:20

## `Duration`

The java.time classes include a pair of classes to represent spans of time. The [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) class is for hours-minutes-seconds, and [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Period.html) is for years-months-days.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofMinutes( 260L );
```

### `Duration` parts

Access each part of the `Duration` by calling `to…Part`. These methods were added in Java 9 and later.

```
long days = d.toDaysPart() ;
int hours = d.toHoursPart() ;
int minutes = d.toMinutesPart() ;
int seconds = d.toSecondsPart() ;
int nanos = d.toNanosPart() ;
```

You can then assemble your own string from those parts.

## ISO 8601

The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines textual formats for date-time values. For spans of time unattached to the timeline, the [standard format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) is `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`. The `P` marks the beginning, and the `T` separates the years-month-days from the hours-minutes-seconds. So an hour and a half is `PT1H30M`.

The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default for parsing and generating strings. The [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) and [`Period`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) classes use this particular standard format. So simply call `toString`.

```
String output = d.toString();
```

> PT4H20M

For alternate formatting, build your own String in Java 9 and later (*not* in Java 8) with the `Duration::to…Part` methods. Or see [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40487511/642706) for using regex to manipulate the ISO 8601 formatted string.

## `LocalTime`

I strongly suggest using the standard ISO 8601 format instead of the extremely ambiguous and confusing clock format of `04:20`. But if you insist, you can get this effect by hacking with the [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class. This works if your duration is not over 24 hours.

```
LocalTime hackUseOfClockAsDuration = LocalTime.MIN.plus( d );
String output = hackUseOfClockAsDuration.toString();
```

> 04:20

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Nice, I'm looking for something like this, but I'd like to get the result as "4h 20m" or "4h 20min" rather than "PT4H20M" or "04:20". I guess I'll have to use some kind of formatting method?

Comment: @aditsuquitbecauseSEisEVIL Java 9 brought the `Duration::to…Part` methods shown my edits to this Answer. You can easily assemble your own string from those parts.

Answer (score 15):

Use `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` to convert minute into hours and minute

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");

try {
    Date dt = sdf.parse("90");
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(dt));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can also use the [TimeUnit](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) class. You could define

```
private static final String FORMAT = "%02d:%02d:%02d";
```

can have a method like:

```
public static String parseTime(long milliseconds) {
      return String.format(FORMAT,
              TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milliseconds),
              TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliseconds) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(
              TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milliseconds)),
              TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(milliseconds) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
              TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliseconds)));
   }
```

Comment: I know it’s a bit longer than the code in the accepted answer, but IMHO it is also clearer. I prefer this.

Answer (score 4):

I use this function for my projects:

```
 public static String minuteToTime(int minute) {
    int hour = minute / 60;
    minute %= 60;
    String p = "AM";
    if (hour >= 12) {
        hour %= 12;
        p = "PM";
    }
    if (hour == 0) {
        hour = 12;
    }
    return (hour < 10 ? "0" + hour : hour) + ":" + (minute < 10 ? "0" + minute : minute) + " " + p;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

(In Kotlin) If you are going to put the answer into a TextView or something you can instead use a string resource:

```
<string name="time">%02d:%02d</string>
```

And then you can use this String resource to then set the text at run time using:

```
private fun setTime(time: Int) {
    val hour = time / 60
    val min = time % 60
    main_time.text = getString(R.string.time, hour, min)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be done like this

```
        int totalMinutesInt = Integer.valueOf(totalMinutes.toString());

        int hours = totalMinutesInt / 60;
        int hoursToDisplay = hours;

        if (hours > 12) {
            hoursToDisplay = hoursToDisplay - 12;
        }

        int minutesToDisplay = totalMinutesInt - (hours * 60);

        String minToDisplay = null;
        if(minutesToDisplay == 0 ) minToDisplay = "00";     
        else if( minutesToDisplay < 10 ) minToDisplay = "0" + minutesToDisplay ;
        else minToDisplay = "" + minutesToDisplay ;

        String displayValue = hoursToDisplay + ":" + minToDisplay;

        if (hours < 12)
            displayValue = displayValue + " AM";
        else
            displayValue = displayValue + " PM";

        return displayValue;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error while converting currency.");
    }
    return totalMinutes.toString();
```

Comment: Gosh, that's verbose - just like FizzBuzz Enterprise Edition: http://www.theospears.com/blog/2007/08/11/fizzbuzz-enterprise-edition/

Comment: What does it have to do with currency?

Answer (score 1):

Given input in seconds you can transform to format hh:mm:ss like this :

```
int hours;
int minutes;
int seconds;
int formatHelper;

int input;


//formatHelper maximum value is 24 hours represented in seconds

formatHelper = input % (24*60*60);

//for example let's say format helper is 7500 seconds

hours = formatHelper/60*60;
minutes = formatHelper/60%60;
seconds = formatHelper%60;

//now operations above will give you result = 2hours : 5 minutes : 0 seconds;
```

I have used formatHelper since the input can be more then 86 400 seconds, which is 24 hours.

If you want total time of your input represented by hh:mm:ss, you can just avoid formatHelper.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Doesn't work. If `input` is 7500, then the result is 7500 hours, 5 minutes and 0 seconds, which is obviously wrong. And the question didn't mention seconds at all.

Comment: @fdermishin is correct. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVFNb8IwDL3nV1iT0MrQaIVgk1Zx2Wl3jtMOgXoQlo8qTgoI8ds7l4YxNiVS7DjvPftlKxv5uK2@2pWWRPB6FHVcarUCCjLw0ThVgZHKZovglV2/f4D0axoeW2UDbFz0VIouNMrGgCkhXDlbpeTTeSPDG@oafSnOV8rWMcAcnmdFwVciz38/Yr29MtFAI3VEUASTaS8FHmuPhDZgxSQXHSFu4PPEP4BsMn14KngPyyQCuJem1ggawz0ByUPqDzY9mNW6rq7UvfD8Zoz8TFqKNPT/6qCrJoo/1XOJm7FuB45zttlZArl0DcJOaQ1rxdHBRZ6Wou58mvRNvMDs4jPHxdXmxYECmrGLYVzzLwVtsx4xgjteox/UJU/IYdmeTu03 "Java (JDK) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

Here is my function for convert a `second`,`millisecond` to `day,hour,minute,second`

```
public static String millisecondToFullTime(long millisecond) {
    return timeUnitToFullTime(millisecond, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

public static String secondToFullTime(long second) {
    return timeUnitToFullTime(second, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

public static String timeUnitToFullTime(long time, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
    long day = timeUnit.toDays(time);
    long hour = timeUnit.toHours(time) % 24;
    long minute = timeUnit.toMinutes(time) % 60;
    long second = timeUnit.toSeconds(time) % 60;
    if (day > 0) {
        return String.format("%dday %02d:%02d:%02d", day, hour, minute, second);
    } else if (hour > 0) {
        return String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);
    } else if (minute > 0) {
        return String.format("%d:%02d", minute, second);
    } else {
        return String.format("%02d", second);
    }
}
```

**Testing**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("60 => " + secondToFullTime(60));
    System.out.println("101 => " + secondToFullTime(101));
    System.out.println("601 => " + secondToFullTime(601));
    System.out.println("7601 => " + secondToFullTime(7601));
    System.out.println("36001 => " + secondToFullTime(36001));
    System.out.println("86401 => " + secondToFullTime(86401));
}
```

**Output**

```
60 => 1:00
101 => 1:41
601 => 10:01
7601 => 2:06:41
36001 => 10:00:01
86401 => 1day 00:00:01
```

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

Minutes mod 60 will gives hours with minutes remaining.

http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/15.html

Comment: Actually it's the opposite, minutes mod 60 will give you the minutes. See my answer

Comment: You're quite right.  It's rather late here, thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

```
int mHours = t / 60; //since both are ints, you get an int
int mMinutes = t % 60;
System.out.printf("%d:%02d", "" +mHours, "" +mMinutes);
```

Comment: Why are you using integer format `%d` to format string values `"" +mHours` and `"" +mMinutes`?

Answer (score 0):

Solution on kotlin [Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.time/-duration/)

```
import kotlin.time.Duration
import kotlin.time.DurationUnit
import kotlin.time.toDuration

val min = 150.toDuration(DurationUnit.MINUTES)
val time = min.toComponents { days, hours, minutes, seconds, nanoseconds -> 
 "$days $hours $minutes $seconds $nanoseconds"
}
```

We get 0 days 2 hours 30 minutes 0 seconds 0 nanoseconds

We can also use

```
DurationUnit.DAYS
DurationUnit.HOURS
DurationUnit.SECONDS
DurationUnit.MILLISECONDS
DurationUnit.MICROSECONDS
DurationUnit.NANOSECONDS
```

Answer (score -1):

```
long d1Ms=asa.getTime();   
long d2Ms=asa2.getTime();   
long minute = Math.abs((d1Ms-d2Ms)/60000);   
int Hours = (int)minute/60;     
int Minutes = (int)minute%60;     
stUr.setText(Hours+":"+Minutes);
```

Comment: above two will supress the presistion numbers

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BasicElement {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int hours;
        System.out.print("Enter the hours to convert:");
        hours =input.nextInt();
        int d=hours/24;
        int m=hours%24;
        System.out.println(d+"days"+" "+m+"hours");     

    }
}
```

Comment: It was minutes to hours and minutes

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Time{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        int totMins=0;
        int hours=0;
        int mins=0;
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the time in mins: ");
        totMins= sc.nextInt();
        hours=(int)(totMins/60);
        mins =(int)(totMins%60);
        System.out.printf("%d:%d",hours,mins);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this differ from the accepted answer?