# How to convert minutes to HH:mm on android?

Tags: java, android, date

I have String variable `movieDuration`, which contains value in minutes. Need to convert that to HH:mm format. How should I do it?

Tried to do it as:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
movieDurationFormatted = formatter.format(movieDuration);
```

But looks like value in minutes is not ok for formatter.

Comment: A `DateFormat` formats a date, not a duration. For the difference, consult a dictionary. For converting minutes into hours I’d recommend checking said dictionary, look for “division.”

Comment: So, are you suggesting manually to divide minutes by 60, take integer part as hours, remainder as minutes?

Comment: LA_, of course because that is exactly how it’s done. :)

Comment: Convert to a `Duration`, for example `Duration movieDuration = Duration.ofMinutes(97);`. Since Java 9 and probably available on Android through desugaring, format like `String.format(Locale.US, "%d:%02d", movieDuration.toHours(), movieDuration.toMinutesPart())`. In this example the result is `1:37`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert minutes to Hours and minutes (hh:mm) in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387371/how-to-convert-minutes-to-hours-and-minutes-hhmm-in-java)

Answer (score 15):

```
public static String formatHoursAndMinutes(int totalMinutes) {
    String minutes = Integer.toString(totalMinutes % 60);
    minutes = minutes.length() == 1 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    return (totalMinutes / 60) + ":" + minutes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just use the following method to convert minutes to HH:mm on android?**

*if you want to process long value then just change the parameter type*

```
public static String ConvertMinutesTimeToHHMMString(int minutesTime) {
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    df.setTimeZone(timeZone);
    String time = df.format(new Date(minutesTime * 60 * 1000L));

    return time;
}
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution on kotlin [Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.time/-duration/)

```
import kotlin.time.Duration
import kotlin.time.DurationUnit
import kotlin.time.toDuration

val min = 150.toDuration(DurationUnit.MINUTES)
val time = min.toComponents { days, hours, minutes, seconds, nanoseconds -> 
 "$days $hours $minutes $seconds $nanoseconds"
}
```

We get 0 days 2 hours 30 minutes 0 seconds 0 nanoseconds

We can also use

```
DurationUnit.DAYS
DurationUnit.HOURS
DurationUnit.SECONDS
DurationUnit.MILLISECONDS
DurationUnit.MICROSECONDS
DurationUnit.NANOSECONDS
```