# Android: How to convert from SystemClock.elapsedRealTime to a human readable CharSeq?

Tags: android, system-clock

How do you convert from [`SystemClock.elapsedRealTime()`](http://android-doc.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime()) to a human readable CharSeq that can be displayed in textview?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Duration.ofMillis(                 // Represent a span of time on scale of hours-minutes-seconds, unattached to the timeline.
    SystemClock.elapsedRealTime()  // 441_000L as an example.
)
.toString()                        // Generate a String in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> PT7M21S

## Avoid Time-of-day Format

Displaying elapsed time in the format of time-of-day (HH:MM:SS.SSS) is misleading and ambiguous as it can easily be misinterpreted as time-of-day.

## ISO 8601 – Duration Format

The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines sensible string representations of various date-time values. These values include elapsed time.

The standard format is `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where the beginning is marked with a `P` while a `T` separates the years-month-days portion from the hours-minutes-seconds portion. For example:

- `PT30M` = a half hour
- `PT8H30M` = eight and a half hours
- `P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S` represents a duration of *"three years, six months, four days, twelve hours, thirty minutes, and five seconds"*.

Often the terms "period" or "duration" are used as synonyms. The terminology in date-time work has not yet been standardized. Note how the standard uses the term "duration", yet the format begins with a `P` as in "period". *C’est la vie*.

## java.time

The *java.time* classes offer two classes to represent a span of time unattached to the timeline:

- `Period`
  years-months-days
- [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html)
  hours-minutes-seconds

Both of these classes parse/generate the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) duration format discussed above.

Your output from [`SystemClock.elapsedRealTime()`](http://android-doc.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime()) is a `long` integer number counting milliseconds elapsed. So we want likely want to use the [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class.

```
long millis = SystemClock.elapsedRealTime() ;
Duration d = Duration.ofMillis( millis ) ;
```

Let’s try 441000 as our millis.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofMillis( 441_000L ) ;
```

Generate the standard formatted string. For `441_000L`, we get seven minutes and 21 seconds.

```
String output = d.toString() ;  // Generate standard ISO 8601 string.
```

> PT7M21S

You can parse the standard strings, to get a `Duration` object.

```
Duration d = Duration.parse( "PT7M21S" ) ;
```

I suggest teaching your users to read the standard ISO 8601 format, as it is readable and unambiguous. I strongly recommend *never* displaying as a time-of-day format (`00:07:21`) as I have seen that ambiguity cause much confusion among users. But if your user-base is not amenable to the standard format, you can generate other strings.

In some later versions of this class, you can call the `to…Part` methods to retrieve the seven and the twenty-one.

```
int minutesPart = d.toMinutesPart() ; // The whole-minutes portion.
int secondsPart = d.toSecondsPart() ; // The whole-seconds portion.
```

You can also get back to a grand total of milliseconds.

```
long millis = d.toMillis() ;  // Not the part, but the entire span of time in terms of milliseconds.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

---

## Joda-Time

**UPDATE:** The *Joda-Time* project is now in maintenance-mode, with the team advising migration to *java.time* classes. I am leaving this section intact for history.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time) library offers three classes to represent a span of time, `Interval`, `Duration`, and `Period`. That last one, `Period`, means a span of time described as a count of days, hours, and such. It parallels this particular ISO 8601 format. The `Period` class also parses and generates strings in the ISO 8601 format. Joda-Time works in Android, is well-worn and quite popular as a replacement for the notoriously troublesome java.util.Date/.Calendar classes.

The `Period` class takes a `long` integer as a count of milliseconds in duration. Just what we need, as [`SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`](http://android-doc.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime()) gives us a count in milliseconds since the machine booted.

```
long machineUptimeMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() ;
Period machineUptimePeriod = new Period( machineUptimeMillis );
String output = machineUptimePeriod.toString(); // Ex: P3DT2H15M37.123S
```

If we are tracking how long some operation takes, we’ll be using a pair of such `long`s in subtraction.

```
long start = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() ;
// … Perform some operation …
long stop = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() ;
long elapsedMillis = stop - start ;
Period elapsedPeriod = new Period( elapsedMillis );
```

### Lowercase

For presentation to human users, you may want to strip out the `P` and/or `T` and use lowercase letters for better readability.

```
String output = elapsedPeriod.toString().replace( "P" , "" ).replace( "T", " " ).toLowerCase() ;
```

For example, `3y6m4d 12h30m5s`.

### Pretty-Print

You can pretty-print `Period` values such as "5 years and 2 months".

Use the built-in [Locale-sensitive word-based formatter](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormat.html#wordBased--).

```
PeriodFormatter formatter = PeriodFormat.wordBased( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ;
String output = formatter.print( elapsedPeriod ) ;
```

Or create your own custom format with a [`PeriodFormatterBuilder`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatterBuilder.html).

```
 PeriodFormatter yearsAndMonths = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
     .printZeroAlways()
     .appendYears()
     .appendSuffix(" year", " years")
     .appendSeparator(" and ")
     .printZeroRarelyLast()
     .appendMonths()
     .appendSuffix(" month", " months")
     .toFormatter() ;
```

Comment: java.time.Period is available in Android API level 26 upwards

Comment: @channae I revised this Answer to (a) give you links to the *ThreeTen-Backport* & *ThreeTenABP* libraries to use in earlier versions of Android, and (b) Stress using *java.time* classes (or the back-port) as the official successor to *Joda-Time* (both projects are led by the same man, [Stephen Colebourne](http://blog.joda.org)).

Answer (score 2):

See the following question: [How to format an elapsed time interval in hh:mm:ss.SSS format in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710094/how-to-format-an-elapsed-time-interval-in-hhmmss-sss-format-in-java). Using this approach:

```
private static String formatInterval(final long millis) {
    final long hr = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis);
    final long min = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hr));
    final long sec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hr) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(min));
    final long ms = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(millis - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hr) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(min) - TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(sec));
    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d", hr, min, sec, ms);
}
```

And then assuming you have a reference to a TextView:

```
long elapsedTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealTime();
textView.setText(elapsedTime);
```

The result is that your TextView will display the total time that your device has been up in a human-readable format.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work if `elapsedRealTime()` returns a value greater than or equal to 24 hours. The problem is `HH` when used with `SimpleDateFormat` can only represent an absolute hour of day from 0-23. Absolute date & time represented by formatting using `SimpleDateFormat` is not the same as elapsed / relative time.

Comment: Still some issues...the `formatInterval(...)` method doesn't need to be `static`. It's only declared that way in the link you posted because it was being called there from the `main()` method of standard Java code. Also in the example of setting the `TextView` you're just passing in `elapsedTime` rather than the result of `formatInterval(...)`. Lastly, the `formatInterval(...)` method is formatting the return `String` to 2 digits for hours causing misleading results after 99 hours, e.g., 105 hours would show as 05. The code should take in to account days as well as hours etc.