# java: compare time/date and get the correct format of time difference

Tags: java, datetime

I have these two times

```
2011-9-5 0:00
2011-9-5 15:50
```

when i get there time difference by

```
Date d1=df.parse(interviewList.get(28).getTime());
Date d2=df.parse(interviewList.get(29).getTime());
long d1Ms=d1.getTime();
long d2Ms=d2.getTime();
diff =  Math.abs((d1Ms-d2Ms)/60000);
```

it gives me correct difference but the difference coming is `950`
How can i get it in a proper format like `15:50` ( which is the diff of above two)

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387371/how-to-convert-minutes-to-hours-and-minutes-hhmm-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It gives you correct difference,

950 minute = 15 hour and 50 min

you can achieve this by

```
int hour = totalMinutes / 60;
int minute = totalMinutes - (hour * 60);
```

and then

```
String dispString = hour + ":" + minute;
```

Comment: He wants to display it in hh:mm