# How to i18n format byte count and time duration

Tags: java, icu

I want to format a message like "Data transfer of 1.0 KiB took 1:32 hours". But I need both byte count and time duration formatted and localized. I found several ideas how to format the byte count, time duration seems fine. But then it comes the localization and my home-grown code becomes excessive.
I am looking for any ideas how such formatting could be implemented with the help of ICU library.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the Java `MessageFormat` which allows you to format different java types to strings; this format should do what you want

```
final MessageFormat format = new MessageFormat("Data transfer of {0,number,0.0} KiB took {1}:{2} hours");
```

Usage would be

```
final String formatted = format.format(new Object[]{amountTransferred, hours, minutes});
```

Where `amountTransferred` is a `double` or `float` or `BigDecimal`, `hours` and `minutes` are integer types.

There is already a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387371/how-to-convert-minutes-to-hours-and-minutes-hhmm-in-java) on how to format a number of minutes to `HH:mm` if you need to do that separately.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not so simple. Imagine the byte count is 1000000 e.g. 1MiB. So I need it formated like 1.0 MiB. And imagine this message is localized in Chinise and MiB should be some Chinise symbol.

Comment: I see what you want - this answer won't do that in its entirety. Maybe some kind soul has a better idea...

Answer (score 0):

ICU has both compact decimals for units (1.0 MiB) and duration formats now. This is a great question, I don't think msgformat supports this natively now.

What you could do is to just use the pattern `{0,number}` without KiB as in Boris' response, but then call `format.setFormat(0,...)` to replace the number formatter with a CompactDecimalFormat  or with a unit formatter.