# What is a very simple way to convert minutes into " x hours y minutes" with inline javascript?

Tags: javascript

I saw a number of examples. Some of these were even using jQuery. What I am looking for is the simplest way to change:

```
var diffMins = 99;
```

into something like "1 hour 39 minutes"

I do this only once in my application so I am not looking to rely on any functions. I would just like to know if the latest java offers a very simple way to do this.

Please note that in the title I use the word Javascript and in the question tag I use the word Javascript. I'm surprised now that two people are asking if it is Java :-(

Comment: You can do a division for hours and a module for minutes

Comment: Are we talking java or javascript?

Comment: I understand the division but how does the module work ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert minutes to Hours and minutes (hh:mm) in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387371/how-to-convert-minutes-to-hours-and-minutes-hhmm-in-java)

Comment: @callback "were even using jQuery" ( it means JavaScript)

Comment: Please note the tag attached to the question. Thanks

Comment: @Alan in your text, "The latest version of Java"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floor for hours and mod60 for minutes:

```
var diffMins = 99;    
Math.floor(diffMins/60) +" Hour "+ diffMins%60 + " Minutes.";
```

[image: Result:]

Answer (score 1):

Use mod operator (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp)

```
parseInt(99/60) + " hour " + (99%60) + " + minutes"
```

http://jsbin.com/xisuqefona/1/edit

Comment: My VS2013 compiler complains about parseInt

Comment: Error 2 Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target:
 Could not apply type 'string' to argument 1 which is of type 'number'.

Comment: @Alan—there's a syntax error: `" + minutes"` should be `+ " minutes"`.

Comment: @Audrey—there is a syntax error. A radix to [*parseInt*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2) is only sensible if the argument is a string. Please reference relevant standards (e.g. ES5) rather than sites like [*w3schools*](http://www.w3fools.com).

Comment: Removed my comment to add radix, the original answer works just fine without radix. Tested in both Chrome and Firefox. IE might be a different beast if anyone can verify.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `/`, `%` and `|` operators:

```
((99/60) | 0) + " hour(s) " + (99%60) + " minute(s)"
```

```js
var diffMins = 99;
var text = ((diffMins / 60) | 0) + " hour(s) " + (diffMins % 60) + " minute(s)";
alert(text);
```