# Java How to get the time when timer is stopped?

Tags: java, swing, timer, awt

I'm currently referring to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745745/creating-a-count-up-timer-to-break-when-puzzle-is-solved-java) to create the timer for my program.

But I don't know how to get the time when `timer` is stopped.

I think `System.getcurrentTimeMillis()` cannot be used at this moment.

So, how can I get the current time when `timer` is stopped with the method mentioned?

EDIT :

I'm currently building a simple 4X4 memory game, and I have timer in my program, using the method from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745745/creating-a-count-up-timer-to-break-when-puzzle-is-solved-java).

At the end of the game, I'll use a `showMessageDialog` to display the number of clicks and time used. However, I'm just able to display the clicks, which is the easiest part.

Based on the method from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745745/creating-a-count-up-timer-to-break-when-puzzle-is-solved-java),  I think I can use an easy way such as

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Congratulations. \n You have win the game with " + click + " click(s) in " + hour + "hour(s) " + minute + " minute(s) " + second + " second(s).", "Win", 1);
```

Is there any better way of doing it?

Comment: What makes you think that `System.getCurrentTimeMillis()` cannot be used?  Since that's the crux of your problem, you need to give some justification for that statement (which initially seems to be just wrong, by the way).

Comment: I not sure I'm correct or not, `System.getcurrentTimeMillis()` return value in `milliseconds`, and the [method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745745/creating-a-count-up-timer-to-break-when-puzzle-is-solved-java) is I'm referring to is in the format of `HH:MM:SS`.

Comment: take a look at SimpleDateFormat

Comment: Hmm... My program is running a timer that in `HH:MM:SS` format, but when I stop the `timer`, I want to get the current time showed by the `timer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Date d = new Date();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
String dateStr = df.format(d);
```