# How to create a Timer that goes backwards

Tags: java, timer, countdown

I'm making a Software  by Java (& Netbeans IDE) and one of the features I would like to add is a timer that can be given a certain time (1 hour) and then let it run backwards till it goes `00:00:00` where it will do a certain action.

I tried to do something with my knowledge of adding a clock to the program but it didn't work. Please help

Answer (score 4):

You could try this:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class CountDown {    
     Timer timer;
     public CountDown() {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new DisplayCountdown(), 0, 1000);
    }
    class DisplayCountdown extends TimerTask {

          int seconds = 60;
          public void run() {
               if (seconds > 0) {
                  System.out.println(seconds + " seconds remaining");
                  seconds--;
               } else {

                  System.out.println("Countdown finished");
                  System.exit(0);
              }    
        }
   }     
   public static void main(String args[]) {

      System.out.println("Countdown Beginning");    
      new CountDown();    
   }    
}
```

Read more: http://www.ehow.com/how_8675868_countdown-tutorial-java.html#ixzz2guYw8c99

Comment: Thank you so much. Quick question: How do I turn seconds to minutes and make show remaining minutes and seconds???

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't continuously run. It simply prints the value I gave for seconds converted to hh:mm:ss instead of continuously going according to seconds.

Comment: Sorry I took time to reply. I had to do every possibility I know using those codes.

Answer (score 0):

I would start a new Thread where it waits 100 milliseconds (`Thread.sleep(1000)`) and then subtract that from hours * 60 /*or minutes*/ * 60 /* or seconds */ * 1000. If the result == 0 then you've hit that time.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to continuously display the countdown? If so, check this out: [Java swing timer not decrementing the right way and not starting at the correct hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204700/java-swing-timer-not-decrementing-the-right-way-and-not-starting-at-the-correct/19204994#19204994)

If not, just use javax.Swing.Timer and set it for non-repeat and 3600 * 1000 millis

Edit: if you are not using Swing, then perhaps java.util.Timer

Comment: OP didn't say if he is using `swing`