# JTable Checkbox should start timer when checked

Tags: java, swing, timer, jtable

I am looking to have a column in a JTable that counts the time that boolean column in the table is 'true' for. It is a timer for how the long the checkbox is checked. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around all of the mechanics for the algorithm.

```
ActionListener actListner = new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
        {
            System.out.println("k");
            aTable.updateTime();
        }
    };

    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, actListner);
    timer.start();

    TableModelListener tableListener = new TableModelListener()
    {
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) 
        {
         int row = e.getFirstRow();
            int column = e.getColumn();
            TableModel model = (TableModel)e.getSource();
            String columnName = model.getColumnName(column);
            Object data = model.getValueAt(row, column);


            if (aTable.data.getVisible(row))
            {
                //aTable.data.setTimeVisible(row, date math);
            }
        }
    };
```

The "updateTime()" function is used for tracking the amount of time a row exists once it is added, and I was thinking about also using that function (since it is called every time by the timer ticking) to set the values for the checkbox checked tracker, but I'm not sure.

```
public void updateTime()
    {
        //data.updateTime();

        Date newTime = new Date();

            Integer time = null;
            System.out.println("updateTime");
            for (int i = 0; i < data.startTime.size(); i++)
            {
                time = Integer.parseInt(data.twoMin.format(new Date(newTime.getTime() - data.startTime.get(i).getTime())));
                //Date waiting = new Date(time);
                if (time >= 10)
                {
                    data.setTimeWaiting(i, data.twoMin.format(new Date(newTime.getTime() - data.startTime.get(i).getTime()))); 
                    System.out.println("2");
                }
                else if (time < 10)
                {
                    data.setTimeWaiting(i, (data.oneMin.format(new Date(newTime.getTime() - data.startTime.get(i).getTime()))));
                    System.out.println("1");
                }


                fireTableRowsUpdated(i,i);
            }

    }
```

Would I need to pass an array with the locations of the start times? This is confusing me.

Comment: A [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would result in better response and less guess work

Comment: don't to call fireTableRowsUpdated(i,i); outside of the models methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an outline of one way to do this:

- In your implementation of [`TableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data), manage a `List<Row>`, where each `Row` contains a `Boolean` for the checkbox and `long` values for the start and stop time; use `System.currentTimeMillis()` as needed.
- Condition the start and stop times in an `ItemListener` in your [`CellEditor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).
- [Render](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) the difference as an elapsed time using a [suitable format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2704473/230513).
- In the `ActionListener` of a [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), periodically invoke `setValueAt()` in the model for each active `Row`; the listening table should update automatically.

A related example is shown [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table).

Comment: Great answer, thank you. One more question: How do I make a List of 'Row'?