# Can you combine a CheckBox and string in one cell in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jlabel, jcheckbox

I'm wondering if it is possible to put a CheckBox and string in one cell. The string would be used to track how long the checkbox was checked for. I'd like the cell to be laid out like the ColorRenderer cell in this [example](http://www.jyloo.com/news/?pubId=1286389179000).

The problem is I can't find a method to set the checkbox on the JLabel.

Comment: You caan define your own renderer class. Use JPanel and place the JCheckBox and the JLabel on the panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the complete example cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602711/jtable-checkbox-should-start-timer-when-checked/23603436#23603436), you can use [`setText()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setText(java.lang.String)) on an instance of your custom [`TableCellRenderer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).

[image]
<sub>(source: [drjohnbmatthews at sites.google.com](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/_/rsrc/1377266543747/table/JTableTest.png))</sub>

Related examples similar to [`ColorRenderer`](http://www.jyloo.com/news/?pubId=1286389179000) are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833482/how-to-represent-double-values-as-circles-in-a-2d-matrix-in-java/2834484#2834484) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744672/set-color-dynamically-based-on-value-java-swing/21756629#21756629).

[image]

[image]